# Proving that a proposed function is a Borel measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, integral-geometry

Suppose $K$ is a fixed compact convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I wish to define a measure $M(K,\cdot):\{Borel subsets of \mathbb{R}^n\} \to \mathbb{R}$ where intuitively $M(K,A)$ (where $A$ is a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$) is going to be the "fraction" of $\partial K$ that lies in $A$, in the following sense:

Let $N(K,A)$ be the set of all vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ consisting of the zero vector and all outer normal vectors of $K$ at points of $\partial K \cap A$. Let $B_n$ be the solid unit sphere, and $\lambda_n$ be the Lebesgue measure. Define

$$M(K,A):= \frac{\lambda_n(N(K,A)\cap B_n)}{\lambda_n(B_n)}$$

[So basically by "fraction", I mean looking at the set of outer unit normal vectors of $\partial K \cap A$ as a fraction of the set of outer unit normal vectors of $\partial K$.]

In order for this definition to work,

- How do we know that $N(K,A)\cap B_n$ is Lebesgue measurable?
- How can we show that $M(K,\cdot)$ is a Borel measure? (my hunch is to exhibit it as a pushforward measure of some other measure)

**Attempt:** I think I can solve these problems if all points of $\partial K$ individually have disjoint unit normal vectors, namely consider the map $S_{n-1} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ by mapping $u$ to the unique point on $\partial K$ that has $u$ as a unit normal vector. This map is continuous, so just pushforward. It is okay if the map is not injective. The problem comes if multiple points on $\partial K$ have the same normal vector. In this case the map is not well-defined and I cannot pushforward.

[For those curious, this function shows up as a "curvature measure" in integral geometry, but I am not convinced how this is a measure in the first place]

Comment: How exactly are you defining an admissible outer normal? Unit normals would make $N(K,A)$ be measure zero in, for instance, the case $K=B(0,1)$. Are all the outer normals with norm *at most* 1 admissible instead?

Comment: @Ian yes, I was allowing my outer normal to be of all possible lengths (not just unit). That's why I intersect with $B_n$ and then normalized against volume of $B_n$

Comment: Then I don't understand why your denominator isn't $\lambda_n(B_n)$.

Comment: @Ian right sorry typo! Edited!

Comment: Wait, now I'm still confused. Should $M$ always be $1$ if $A \supset \partial K$? In particular should $M$ always be $1$ if $A=\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @Ian Yes, if $A$ contains $\partial K$, then $M(K,A)=1$. But $A$ is just an arbitrary Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and so it might not contain $\partial K$. So for each Borel $A$, I will get some real number between 0 and 1 inclusive. I hope that this mapping $A \mapsto number$ is a measure. ($K$ is fixed, I am feeding $A$ into the function) I have clarified the quesiton further, hope it clears the confusion.

Comment: What happens if you have two disjoint regions of $\partial K$ which have the same unit normals? Or is this possibility ruled out by convexity? (My ideas are concave or disconnected.) It seems like this would be the only obstacle to $N(K,A)$ being a measure (albeit not necessarily a measure defined on all Borel sets).

Comment: It might be ruled out by convexity...

Answer (score 0):

For Borel A, N(K, A) is analytic hence measurable. It may not be Borel though.

Comment: I am not requiring that $N(K,A)$ is a Borel measurable subset, just wanting that the map $M(K,\cdot)$, with domain being Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, is a measure. I have re-clarified my question above.

Comment: Additional question! How did exactly did you conclude that $N(K,A)$ is analytic?